# How to automatically style HTML output of kramdown converter?

Tags: html, css, kramdown

I'm writing notes in kramdown, then using the `kramdown` converter to get an html file to read locally (not on a server).

```
$ kramdown notes.txt > notes.html
```

My workflow is to continually update `notes.txt`, then render `notes.html` quickly to view it.

I want to style the notes, so I made a CSS file `notes_style.css` that formats the HTML body:

```
body {
...
}
```

I added a `<head>` tag to `notes.txt` and put in a link to my stylesheet. Then I put `<body>` tags around the contents of `notes.txt`:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="txt/css" href="themes/notes_style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

I then realized that, since `kramdown` ignores HTML blocks, nothing in `<body>` is converted to HTML. How am I supposed to style the contents of `<body>` while being able to convert the kramdown to HTML? I don't want to manually add in `<body>` tags every time I use `kramdown`.

I suspect that something's wrong with my workflow, but not sure what the right way to do it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kramdown has the [`parse_block_html` option](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html#option-parse-block-html) that causes it to parse the contents of HTML elements. You can use it like this:

```
$ kramdown --parse-block-html notes.txt > notes.html
```

Alternatively, Kramdown also looks for a [special `markdown` attribute on HTML elements](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks). If it is set to `'1'`, then Kramdown will parse the contents of that element as markdown. So you could do this (you need the quotes around `1`, Kramdown’s HTML parser is quite strict):

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="txt/css" href="themes/notes_style.css" />
</head>
<body markdown='1'>
Content here will be parsed _as Markdown_.
</body>
```

In both cases, your `body` content needs to be left aligned as normal, you can’t indent it as you might naturally do writing HTML nested inside an element.